# Unexpected bytes when reading a file

Tags: encryption, cryptography

So i have been working on an encryption algorithm and i wanted to see if it'd successfuly encrypt a text file (i want the program to be versatile so it's reading bytes).

I run the program, encryption works (amount of letter match the amount of letters in plain text) fine BUT whenever i try to read the encrypted file it adds a random byte. `\xc3\x81` to be exact.

For example:

if plain text is `"noob"` decrypted text is, for some reason, `Ánoob`. `"Á"` being the random byte.

Here's the code,

```
.
.
.
# I tried avoiding the byte by adding the statements about 193
# I couldn't add some of the
# While loops are there to make sure the byte is within supported ascii range

def encryption_algorithm(self):

    NBYTE = b''

    for file in self.file_path_generator(): # self.file_path_generator() just gets the list of files

        if file.name != os.path.basename(__file__):

            read = self.access_files(file, None ,"rb", False, False) # same thing as "with open("filename", "rb") as f:"

            for byte in read:

                if byte % 5 == 0 and byte != 193:

                    byte = (byte + 30)

                    while byte > 255:

                        byte -= 255

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")
                
                elif byte % 5 == 4 and byte != 193:

                    byte = (byte + 2)

                    while byte > 255:

                        byte -= 255

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")

                elif byte == 193:

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")
                
                else:

                    byte = (byte + 1)

                    while byte > 255:

                        byte -= 255

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")

            self.access_files(file, NBYTE, "wb", False, False)


def decryption_algorithm(self):

    NBYTE = b''

    for file in self.file_path_generator():

        if file.name != os.path.basename(__file__):

            read = self.access_files(file, None ,"rb", False, False)

            for byte in read:

                if byte % 5 == 0 and byte != 193:

                    byte = (byte - 30)

                    while byte < 0:

                        byte += 255

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")
                
                elif byte % 5 == 1 and byte != 193:

                    byte = (byte - 2)

                    while byte < 0:

                        byte += 255

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")

                elif byte == 193:

                    NBYTE += (chr(byte), "utf-8")
                
                else:

                    byte = (byte - 1)

                    while byte < 0:

                        byte += 255

                    NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")
                    

            self.access_files(file, NBYTE, "wb", False, False)
```

Note: Replacing the `"Á"` with `None` does work for text files but not image files.

Note2: I'd add the full encrypted text aswell but some characters are not supported. It was something like `"?ppc"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utf-8 can use more than one byte.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

with your example noob. n=0x6e when you add 30.
The result is 140 (0x8c).
And it will need 2 bytes to be encoded in utf-8 .
you can try:

```
NBYTE = b''
byte=140
NBYTE += bytes(chr(byte), "utf-8")
print(NBYTE)
```

you will see that the result will be:

```
b'\xc2\x8c'
```